# I want to copy data from three arrays into one array

Tags: .net, c++-cli

```
array<Byte>^one = gcnew array<Byte>(size);
array<Byte>^two = gcnew array<Byte>(size);
array<Byte>^three = gcnew array<Byte>(size);

array<Byte>^complex = gcnew array<Byte>(3*size);
```

I want to copy data from first, second and third array into complex array. How do I copy ?

Comment: You could have a look at Buffer.BlockCopy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution would be to use [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) which is designed for copying arrays of primitive types. The alternative (if they aren't arrays of primitives) would be to use [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) which takes into account the type stored in the array.

Therefore I would propose:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy( one, 0, complex, 0, size );
Buffer.BlockCopy( two, 0, complex, size, size );
Buffer.BlockCopy( three, 0, complex, (size*2), size );
```